How to make protected route work in node.js
I'm working on a MEAN stack application. Where the user logs in using google oauth so i created a google oauth middleware as a function and linked it in server.js like
  app.use('/protected',googlemiddleware);

and use it below express Router declaration. And the previous api's that use /protected as a route works fine.
Now when i create a new api under the /protected route like

/protected/cashfree/create

it is not even calling the route even after placing it under the /protected route in server.js like
app.use('/protected', googlemiddleware); 
app.post('/protected/cashfree/create', create);

for /protected/cashfree/create api i declare the route like
router.post('/protected/cashfree/create', async(req,res)=>{

//do stuff
});

exports.module = router;

for googlemiddleware i declare it as a function like
const googlemiddleware = async(req,res,next)=>{

//decode google jwt stuff

}
exports.module = {
googlemiddleware
};

server.js
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const cors = require("cors");
const router = express.Router();
//=====================start call routers over here====================
const registerlogin = require("./auth/registerlogin.js");
const userDetails = require("./db/userDetails.js");
const historydownload = require('./core/gethistorydownload.js');
const addupdateprofile = require('./core/add-update-profile.js');
const getprofile = require('./core/getprofile.js');
const stripe = require('./stripe/stripe-intent.js');
const tokencheck = require("./jsonmiddleware/tokencheck.js");
const paymentIntent = require('./stripe/payment-intents.js');
const stripeclientsecret = require('./stripe/stripeClientSecret.js');
const confirmPayment = require('./stripe/confirmpayment.js');
const gptgenerator = require('./core/gptgenerator.js');
const resumedownload = require('./core/resumedownload.js');
const getpaymentdetails = require("./core/getpayments.js");
const getstoredcarddetails = require("./stripe/storedcardpayment.js");
const makepayments4mstoredcard =require('./stripe/storedcardpaymentprocessor.js');
const storedcardresults = require('./stripe/storedcard3ds.js');
const usagedownloaddatacount = require('./core/usage-downloadcount.js');
const usagedownloadcheck = require("./core/usagecheck.js");
//----------------------- CASHFREE STARTS-------------------------------
const createOrder = require('./cashfree/createorder.js');

//----------------------- CASHFREE ENDS-------------------------------
//====================End calling routers after here ===================
// @ts-ignore
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
// @ts-ignore
const htmlDocx = require('html-docx-js');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const LRU = require('lru-cache');

const { stdout, exit } = require('process');
const app = express();
const googlemiddleware = require('./jsonmiddleware/googlemiddleware.js');
const dbmiddleware = require('./db/dbmiddleware.js');
const { create } = require("domain");


// Set up express-session
// Initialize the session middleware directly on the app object
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "blah!blah!blah!",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);
app.use(cors({
  exposedHeaders: ['Authorization'],
}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use('/protected/:subpath', googlemiddleware);
//------------------------- CASHFREE STARTS ------------------------
app.post('/protected/cashfree/createorder', createOrder);


//------------------------- CASHFREE ENDS ------------------------

app.post("/protected/resume/tokencheck", tokencheck);

app.post("/resume/authcheck", userDetails); // Mount the router under the '/authcheck' path
app.post("/registerlogin", registerlogin);
app.get('/protected/history/resume',historydownload);
app.post("/protected/history/resume/generate", gptgenerator);
app.post("/protected/history/resume/download", resumedownload);
app.post("/protected/history/resume/usagedownloadcount", usagedownloaddatacount);
app.get("/protected/history/resume/usagedownloadcheck/:u_id", usagedownloadcheck);
app.post('/protected/profile/addupdate',addupdateprofile);
app.get('/protected/profile/getprofile', getprofile);
app.post('protected/payment/stripe',stripe);
app.post("/protected/payments/payment-intent", paymentIntent);
app.get("/protected/payments/client-secret", stripeclientsecret);
app.post("/protected/payments/confirm-payment", confirmPayment);
app.use("/protected/payments/storedcardapi", getstoredcarddetails);
app.post("/protected/payments/storedcardpaymentsapi",makepayments4mstoredcard);
app.post("/protected/payments/storedcardsresult", storedcardresults);
app.post("/protected/details/getpayments", getpaymentdetails);//same as storedcardapi API.


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, this is the root path!');
});


const cache = new LRU({ max: 100 });
const generateHTML = require('./core/generate.js').generateHTML;



// Define an endpoint to download a resume
app.post('/protected/resume/download', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const resumeData = req.body.resumeData;
    const theme = req.body.theme;

    // Generate the resume
    const resume = await generateHTML(resumeData, theme,'pdf');

    // Send the resume to the client
    // res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.status(200).send(resume);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});

async function convertHtmlToImage(html, theme) {
  // Create a temporary file to store the HTML
  const tempFile = fs.mkdtempSync('');
  const htmlFilePath = `${tempFile}/resume.html`;
  fs.writeFileSync(htmlFilePath, html);

  // Convert the HTML to an image using the wkhtmltopdf command-line tool
  const childProcess = spawn('wkhtmltopdf', ['--quiet', '--print-media-type', 'all', '--no-collate', '--disable-smart-shrinking', '--margin-top', '0', '--margin-bottom', '0', '--margin-left', '0', '--margin-right', '0', '--page-size', 'A4', htmlFilePath, `${tempFile}/resume.${theme}.png`]);

  // Wait for the child process to exit
  await childProcess.on('exit', () => {});

  // Read the image file
  const image = await fs.promises.readFile(`${tempFile}/resume.${theme}.png`);

  // Remove the temporary file
  fs.rmdirSync(tempFile, { recursive: true });

  // Return the image
  return image;
}


app.post('/protected/resume/render', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const resumeData = req.body.resumeData;
    const theme = req.body.theme;
    const fs = require('fs').promises;
  
  const user_data = await dbmiddleware.getConditionalData('user','email',req.decodedjwt.email)  
  
    // Generate the resume
    const resume = await generateHTML(resumeData, theme,'html',user_data.data[0].u_id);
    

    const resumeresult={"resume": resume.output,"data": resume,success: true,message: "Resume generated successfully",status:200};
    console.log("RESUME  RESULT",resumeresult,"RESUME  RESULT")

    //wait for a few seconds and delete generated files after the result has been sent
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    
    await fs.unlink(resume.file); // Delete the generated resume file
    await fs.unlink(resume.json); // Delete the JSON file
    // await fs.unlink(`${resume.file}.html`);
    res.status(200).send(resumeresult);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});



app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
  
});

googlemiddleware.js:
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const path = require('path');
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'g_cred.json');

let c_id;
readFile(filePath, 'utf-8')
  .then((data) => {
    c_id = JSON.parse(data);
 
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // console.log(err, "error reading google json file");
  });

console.log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
let access_token;
let refresh_token;
const dbmiddleware = require('../db/dbmiddleware');

const googlemiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
  const client = new OAuth2Client({
    clientId: c_id.web.client_id,
    clientSecret: c_id.web.client_secret,
    redirectUri: c_id.web.redirect_uris[0],
  });
  const headerToken = req.headers.authorization ? req.headers.authorization : req.rawHeaders[1];
  if (!headerToken) {
    res.status(401).json({ status: 401, success: false, message: "Not Authorized" });
  }
  const token = headerToken.split(' ');
  try {
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token[1],
      audience: c_id.web.client_id,
    });
    console.log(ticket,"ORIGINAZL DATA id ");

    req.decodedjwt = ticket.payload;

    next();
  } catch (err) {

    if (err) {
      try {
        const emailRegex = /"email":"([^"]+)"/;
        const match = err.message.match(emailRegex);
        let email;
        if (match) {
          email = match[1];
          // // console.log('Extracted email:', email);
        } else {
          // // console.log('Email not found in the error message.');
          email = '';
        }
        // // console.log(err,'Extracted email:', email);
        const result = await dbmiddleware.getConditionalData('user', 'email', email);
        const newAccessToken = await refreshAccessToken(client, result.data[0].refresh_token);
        // console.log(newAccessToken, "newAccessToken");
        // Set the Authorization header in the response
        const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
          idToken: newAccessToken,
          audience: c_id.web.client_id,
        });
        req.decodedjwt = ticket.payload;
        res.setHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`);
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Authorization');
     
         next();
      } catch (error) {
        // console.error('Error refreshing access token:', error);
      }
    }
  }
};

const refreshAccessToken = async (client, refreshToken) => {
  try {
    const { tokens } = await client.refreshToken(refreshToken);
    // // console.log(tokens, "tokens");
    return tokens.id_token;
  } catch (error) {
    // console.error('Error refreshing access token:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};


module.exports = googlemiddleware;

createorder.js
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();
const dbmiddleware = require('../db/dbmiddleware');

const axios = require('axios');
console.log("called cashfree");
router.post('/cashfree/createorder',async(req,res)=>{
    try {
    console.log("called cashfree 11111111111111");
    //do stuff
        }catch(error){
            console.log("error 500",error);
          
        }
});

module. Exports=router;


This could have many reasons. If your middleware is not called using these commands, see the code above the command your calling your middleware. The app.use() function could allready be called there. For a chain, the next() function would have to be called to trigger the next middleware.
Someting like:
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Middleware 1');
  next();
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
   console.log('Middleware 2');
   next();
});

Additionally i would change the router to:
router.post('/cashfree/create', async(req,res)=>{

//do stuff
});

exports.module = router;

Now you can use the router with this command in server.js
app.use('/protected', myrouter)

It's more cleane. Because if you call a router like you did it won't work,
because when you call it like
app.use('/protected', router);

than you are allready in the protected segment of the URL.
and you are using it again in the router like:
router.post('**/protected**/cashfree/create', async(req,res)=>{

//do stuff
});

exports.module = router;

So your route would be /protected/protected/cashfree/create.
Best regards.

i couldn't comphrehend completely, can you elaborate the code

i added full code, can you elaborate the code after finding whats wrong with my code above. All the other /protected/** routes work perfectly
